# Working with Drupal in latest Openshift version

Tags: drupal, openshift

I have a couple of working Drupal installations on OpenShift. I prefer OpenShift for testing and development.

However of late when I try to install a new instance of Drupal the 'php' folder is missing and as a result editing of any files is a real nightmare. I decided to create a 'php' folder and build my drupal from there.

The challenge however has been that with every update that I push my settings.php file is deleted and I have to fix it via SSH just to get working. This is a real bother and am looking for a better alternative to working with Drupal in peace on OpenShift.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the 'php' folder is missing". In my OpenShift instance, there is a php folder under /var/lib/openshift, which has the core PHP 5.3 files. Are you referring to a php folder under app-root?

Comment: Ok, I took a look at the drupal-example repo on Github, and I understand now. The old one used a php folder under app-root/runtime/repo (i.e., the root of the Git repository), which contained Drupal (including the sites directory). Now the build hooks install Drupal to a data directory and then symlink it in to app-root/runtime/repo/php

Answer (score 2):

The QuickStart has changed to automatically deploy a Drupal instance in your data dir and symlink the changes.  This means at create time you get the latest Drupal and you can configure and deploy Drupal live.  If you prefer the old model, just copy the php folder off the gear and check it in to your source repo.  The hooks (which you can also change) won't deploy Drupal if you have a php folder - meaning your base Drupal still works.

We made this change so that folks creating a new instance got something running immediately that was up to date with security patches (and so you install modules to the server directly).  Settings.php lives in your data directory and is symlinked in vs being copied.

You can continue to use the old Drupal-example repo as well.

Comment: Clayton, what if you want to scale the Drupal cartridge to multiple gears? This is my 2nd day of using OpenShift, so I am still new, but I am thinking I could do something like create a new directory in my repository into which I would check in the sites directory, add all my themes & modules locally, and then use the build hooks to symlink in that directory instead. Would that work? What about for files? How would I get them to propagate across multiple gears?